# Setting upload_max_filesize (etc) for large file uploads

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, php

I'm trying to upload files via this jQuery plugin: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

I am able to upload files up to 1.2GB without a problem.  The next largest file I've tried is 1.8GB and this upload fails.  I have set:

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 0

memory_limit = 4000M
post_max_size = 3500M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M
```

What should these values be if this isn't working?  I need to upload video files that are up to 2GB via this method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to make that change in the php.ini file

Comment: Yeah those changes are already set in my php.ini and are reflected in phpinfo() - The issue is that it just doesn't let me upload the very large files.  I think Paul may be onto something though with only 2GB being assigned to my shared area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possibly you're on shared hosting so the memory is limited. and 1.8GB sounds to me like something nearly 2GB, this is the limit on 32-bit system for integer, applies to PHP also.

Comment: I think this must just be it.  I tried a file just a bit smaller (1.7GB) and it worked.  It's probably that they've assigned only 2GB to my account and I was just hitting the limit.  Thanks!  We'll encode a bit smaller