# PHP upload drops with big files (w/o error)

Tags: php, apache, upload, limit

I'm using Xampp (on win server 2003) and I've granted both PHP and Apache for uploads with 6GB limit and no time limit for waiting for system processes.
When I'm trying to post a form with uploaded file that is above ~1.8GB, it waits till 100% is uploaded and then refreshes the form with blank fields. No error messages, no routing to form's target page - same page from scratch.

Is there any hidden limitation or file system limitation that does it?
If so, could you please suggest better (free) upload way for PHP?

Thank you in advance,
Mark.

Edit: The limit is on 2GB not 1.8GB

Comment: Have you set both post_max_size and upload_max_size? Altough 1.8 GB is a strange number for the download to stop. Maybe the partition PHP uses to store the temporarily uploaded file is full?

Comment: Post your modified configuration settings in php.ini, which were done to enable the uploads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694177/setting-upload-max-filesize-etc-for-large-file-uploads

Comment: The system is 64bit, shared station. upload_max_filesize = 6000M, post_max_size = 6000M, memory_limit = 6001M.

Comment: @Mark Stupid question: you have set_time_limit(0), right?

Comment: @Claudrian I've set the max_execution_time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading gigabytes, consider writing a web server module. It seems the common sense way to go... And make everything 64bit, just to be sure.

I never even imagined that PHP could take such large of uploads. I'd never rely on it to handle such stuff. **And don't know if PHP can handle the GBs sizes properly... with it 64bit-less support (it uses 32bit) for integers...**

**I'm just guessing here.** *I would write a server module for such tasks that would handle the uploads exactly as I wanted them.*

Comment: 32-bit PHP uses 32-bit integers; but if you've built PHP as 64-bit, it uses 64-bit integers.... don't assume it's limited to 32-bit

Comment: AFAIK, there is no 64bit Xampp. May Wamp be the solution for me?

Comment: If you wanted 64-bit PHP on Windows, you'd need to build it yourself; or find somebody else that had built it and made their downloads available - http://www.anindya.com/ - and run it with 64-bit Apache too

Comment: In Windows longs are always 32bit while long long are 64bit. PHP uses long as it's integer representation afaik. Gotta check out the source a bit :)

Comment: @Mark Told you. One of the perks of PHP. Just like no core unicode support and 32bit-ness on Windows. And no multithreading... Consider the web server module or a custom server listening on another port to receive only file uploads.